# Select all (Ctrl+a) keyboard button not working for input filed inside the HTML5 sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I've used [this HTML5 sortable plugin](http://farhadi.ir/projects/html5sortable/) for drag-drop. Inside that draggable section, I've [editable text](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/) filed. At the time of editing, when I tried to select all text of input field by keyboard command ctrl + a, I noticed that the text had not been selected. At first, I don't understand what's the problem. For testing, I put a normal textarea inside sortable content and noticed that also not works! So, this is the issue of HTML5 sortable plugin. [Here is my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/gm9tybt2/) where you can see that first editable text's `input` (which is outside/above of "Sortable Content start:" text) is working by ctrl + a command where remaining `input` fields inside sortable content don't work with ctrl + a. How can I fix this?

Comment: try to bind a keypress event, if you detect a ctrl.a (looking into event object), you copy the content text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding this to your code should do it:

```
$('.section-sortable').keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey) {
        e.target.select()
    }

})
```

It basically listens to keydown event on your section and if the keydown detects a Ctrl-A it "selects" the target.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gm9tybt2/3/)

Comment: Looks fine! Thank you, can you please tell me what's for 65?